# How to pre-evaluate statements in thymeleaf in concatenations?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

if price is null, nothing is shown: `th:text="${row?.price}`

if price is null, actually '*null*' is printed: `th:text="${row?.price + ' ' + row?.currency}`

How can I tell thymeleaf to evaluate the statements itself before printing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `th:if` to conditionally show a HTML tag:

```
<span th:if="${row?.price}" th:text="${row.price + ' ' + row.currency}"/>
```

The `th:if` is evaluated before the `th:text`.

If you want to hide the currency independent from the price, you can do this:

```
<div>
  <span th:if="${row?.price}" th:text="${row.price}"/>
  <span th:if="${row?.currency}" th:text="${row.currency}"/>
</div>
```

For the space, add a `&nbsp;` between the `span` elements, or use CSS to style it like you want.

Comment: Well but I want to hide the price field if price field is null, and independently hide currency field if currency is null. With this, eg only the currency might be displayed if price is null, or only price is shown if currency is null. Or both is hidden. Or none is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work as follows, but which feels ugly. If anybody has a better idea, please still answer.

```
th:text="|${row.price ?: ''} ${row.currency ?: ''}|"
```